# Where should I put my eclipse workspace on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, eclipse

I'm installing Eclipse on a new computer and I am stuck on deciding where to put the workspace. Java is not my primary language and I haven't paid attention to this setting on previous installs; so what is the workspace used for and how I should approach choosing a location for it? A bit of background: I don't even know if I will be using one or multiple workspaces down the road.

Answer (score 2):

The workspace is just simply the folder that Eclipse will put your Projects (The code you worked on) in. You can put this anywhere, but it usually is put in the users home directory `/home/(user)/` or `~/` on UNIX or UNIX-Like Systems or `C:\Users\(User)` on Windows systems. It's not critical to Java that you have this folder. You don't need to worry about it that much really.

Answer (score 1):

The workspace is mostly metadata on the code. The source code itself doesn't need to be in the workspace directory tree(*), so you really have two choices to make.

A criteria I use is backups: whatever is under my home is backed up often. Source code for professional projects being shared with other people and the Git server, local backups are much less important, so I put things like this under a `/projects` directory. My pet personal projects go under `/home/me/Code` (but I don't use Java for my pet personal projects:))

(*) I tend to use separate directories